# Color grouping by array index, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
const colors = ['#54AAED', '#7BEA6B', '#f8b653', '#ff5584']
```

What I'm trying to build is a function that would return color based on parameter group and index. for instance:

```
function groupColor(i, group) {}
```

The function should return:

```
groupColor(0, true); output <== '#54AAED'
groupColor(1, true); output <== '#54AAED' Minus 10% RGB
```

If group, so Index 0 is `#54AAED` 1 is `#54AAED` minues 10% opacity,
Index 2 is `#7BEA6B` Index 3 is `#7BEA6B` minus 10% opacity, and so on... So Far I've did:

```
function hexToRgb(hex, opacity) {
  return 'rgba(' + (hex = hex.replace('#', '')).match(new RegExp('(.{' + hex.length/3 + '})', 'g')).map(function(l) { return parseInt(hex.length%2 ? l+l : l, 16) }).concat(opacity||1).join(',') + ')';
}

function generateColor({ i, group }) {
  if (group) {
    console.log('should group...')
  }
  const isEven = i % 2 === 0

  console.log('index', hexToRgb(palette[i], 0.9))
  return hexToRgb(palette[i])
}
```

What I was thinking to do is check if index is odd, and by jumps of 2 indexes group, if bool is true.. But I'm kinda stuck here... not sure how to group by intervals of 2, and first should aim for full color, second take same color and set the opacity to 0.9...

Example Usage:

```
const colors = ['#54AAED', '#7BEA6B', '#f8b653', '#ff5584']
const groupMe = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
groupMe.map(entry => {
 return generateColor(i, true)
})
// expected output
'one' <== '#54AAED' opacity 1
'two' <== '#54AAED' opacity 0.9
'three' <== '#7BEA6B' opacity 1
'four' <== '#7BEA6b' opacity 0.9
and so on...
```

Comment: please add some wanted results. what is group doing?

Comment: @NinaScholz I've added example usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the number is even go to previous index. and use ternary to set opacity. React example:

```js
const Component = React.Component
const palette = ['#54AAED', '#7BEA6B', '#f8b653', '#ff5584', '#d743c4', '#76bbf1', '#95ee89', '#f9c575', '#ff9d6d', '#ff779d', '#df69d0', '#9178ec'];
function hexToRgb(hex, opacity) {
  return 'rgba(' + (hex = hex.replace('#', '')).match(new RegExp('(.{' + hex.length/3 + '})', 'g')).map(function(l) { return parseInt(hex.length%2 ? l+l : l, 16) }).concat(opacity||1).join(',') + ')';
}

function generateColor({ i, group }) {
  const isEven = i % 2 === 0
  if (group) {
   return hexToRgb(palette[isEven ? i : i - 1], isEven ? 1 : 0.9)
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const itirations = 10;
    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', width: '50%', marign: '0 auto' }}>
        {Array.from(Array(itirations), (_, i) =>
          <div style={{ width: 300, height: 10, marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: generateColor({ i, group: true }) }} />           
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('mount')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="mount"></div>
```